# What could be enabling --vi-keys in GNU Info

Tags: emacs, vi, info

Though I'm not invoking Info with the --vi-keys option, it seems to be in effect: e.g., though the help states...

```
'?' lists all Info commands;
```

...hitting `?` actually invokes "Regexp search backward". I've verified that there are no aliases for info in effect.

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I don't have the problem when I run info within emacs - only when I run info standalone.

Answer (score 0):

A common shell (bash or zsh) alias is:

```
alias info='info --vi-keys'
```

You can check your aliases to see if this exists with:

```
alias | grep vi-keys
```

If that is the case, look for it in personal and system start-up
files, and remove the line.

Comment: I noticed that alias (and unaliased it) before posting. Problem remained. I'm wondering what other system conf files, env vars, etc. might be capable of overriding the emacs defaults. It's not that I can't use emacs bindings - they're mostly defined to - but `?` doesn't bring up list of commands, and some other keys seem to be overridden for vi purposes.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.infokey` file in play? This has a high precedence in settings. https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Custom-Key-Bindings

Comment: No. I checked in my home directory and even did a system-wide find for anything with '*infokey*' in the name.